# How to set up an IDE on a remote server?

Tags: eclipse, ide, cloud

Im interested in doing some development from my iPad, and one idea I had would be to code from the safari browser. Does anyone know of a way to set up eclipse on a cloud-based server, so that it can be accessed from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you will need the following parts to make it work

- The cloud server must be based on one of the supported Eclipse [Target Environments](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=eclipse#target_environments).
- The cloud server provider must support UI based on some sort of remote desktop - e.g. VNC. Be aware that many cloud providers does not allow UI.
- iPad must support the same remote desktop technology. There seem to be many VNC implementations for iPad...

I guess the difficult part is to find a cloud server to use. Though you, as an alternative, could use any PC with an VNC server where you have Internet access...